# Can Entanglement be use to make observations of early cosmology?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

There apparently was recent experimental validation of a protocol (ref 1) which allows an exchange of energy between 2 individuals who have entangled spin chains and one user passes a classical key to the other user.  While this is characterized as pulling energy from the vacuum, it does open up teleportation options that were not previously envisioned. The thought is that CMB observations do in fact provide us with a classical key associated with the early universe and opens up a question as to whether there are schema to use entanglement with now unreachable sections of the universe to make observations about those co-evolved sections?

For proof the protocol is within current mainstream experimentation and below is initial paper and initial experimental results.

[1. Physicists Use Quantum Mechanics to Pull Energy out of Nothing](https://www.quantamagazine.org/physicists-use-quantum-mechanics-to-pull-energy-out-of-nothing-20230222/?fbclid=IwAR1cf4gGlximx85eiNm_Sbm87L5ewpr5RQxKST5oiBW9Tf1XlRBsdFWrejA_aem_AYcl9B9rtbTLCC1SKR--Zom4tWnOgWoeitooUDiS0NovHzEW0xwAq9-Kz9eEZFXV0Z4)

[2. A Protocol for Quantum Energy Distribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1512)

[3. Experimental Activation of Strong Local Passive States with Quantum Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16269)

Comment: I suppose if you explained the energy teleportation protocol and how you suggest to apply it to the CMB it would improve the question a lot, making it sound less like science fiction.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

Sure, there could  conceivably be particle pairs from the [Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) (CMBR) that are entangled even today. But which ones? There is no way to discern such entangled photons from ones that are not entangled.

Further, you need someone to send a classical signal so that entangled photon could tell us something.  No classical signal can emerge that in any way encodes information from an entangled pair.  I.e. we need a coded classical signal to decode today.  Who was around then to send such a signal, and how would we discern that from the normal CMBR or from other sources (such as light from stars in far away galaxies)? Perhaps it would be in some different wavelength/spectrum, but where would we begin to look?

On the other hand: the [Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_Microwave_Anisotropy_Probe) (WMAP) has analyzed photons from the CMBR to create an incredible map of the early universe (approx. age 375,000 years old).  I doubt we'll be able to go much past that (and we're lucky to be able to go back that far).  But it is fun to imagine what we might have found if we could see further back.  For now, we will have to be satisfied with what we get from the relatively new [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) (launched 2021, first photos 2022).

Comment: To be fair were we able to detect the cosmic neutrino background in a similar fashion to the CMB then we'd have a window within a second of the big bang, so much wishful thinking of course...

Comment: Recent analysis of ICB indicates a detectable contribution of either cosmic neutrino background or possibly new physics https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.09152.pdf